# How to create deep link commands for telegram bot?

Tags: deep-linking, referrals

How can I deep link with Telegram bot commands? What are the commands I need to type? So I'm preparing a bot with a reference system. I want the user who registered from the bottom level to the top to follow the person who registered with the reference link.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to set up a cascade reference bot. For example, when a user who invites a member in the 1st level goes up to the next level, the 2 people he added with the invitation code will go up to the top level only as his/her sub-member. How can I set up such a reference system